# Android Studio Swipe to Change Screen

Tags: java, android

Hello I am pretty new to Android Studio and I was looking but could not find out how to make app functionality so I can change the screen of my app by swiping any help of links or videos is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Is there something you have already tried?

Comment: start seraching viewpagers

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) for that matter. It's used hand in hand with [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) so I suggest, if you haven't, that you look into that too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a recycleView list.  Then you'll need to override the swipe handlers.  Then you'll need to program the onSwipe() method to change the activity.  Screens can be changed like so:

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), activity_main.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
```